# Not able to install 15.5 in opensuse using DockerFile

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, dockerfile, opensuse

I used DockerFile to build image where i want to install postgre 15.5. I have used below line in my code. But seems when i go into the container using docker exec and then check for postgre version installed it says it is 15.3 version

```
# install postgres
RUN zypper --non-interactive --quiet addrepo --refresh -p 90  http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:database:postgresql/15.5/ PostgreSQL
RUN zypper --gpg-auto-import-keys ref
RUN zypper --non-interactive in postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
```

I need 15.5 to be installed. Can anyone help?

Tried different option but did not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try using this command on your docker file
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
and using your custom version from this link:
http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/pool/15/p/postgresql-15/
hope its help